# Streaming JSON to Redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, ioredis

I have a large JSON file that I would like to store it in Redis. The problem is when I parse it I run out of memory in Node.Js

I extended the heap memory from 1.39GB from 4GB it's still happening and I believe I am not doing it properly.

With a lot of search, I found out that streaming is my best bet. The thing is I am not really fluent with Streaming and **I am not sure even this would resolve my problem**

I read a lot and there is a lot of scattered information. I was wondering to ask if you think if this is even approachable or if this is correct?

Would I be able to stream a JSON object into Redis? 
Do I have to Staingifiying it or it will be automatically? 
Should I stringify my json chunk by chunk? 
or streaming into redis will end up being a string?

I am using ioRedis client to interact with Redis.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that only one processor will be updating that key, you could possibly use [SETRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/setrange). As you parse the file, you can keep a reference to the next offset:

(psuedo-code)

```
offset = 0
offset = redis.set_range(key, offset, "string")
```

Then you can load pieces of the file up to Redis without having to load everything into memory at once.

`SETRANGE` returns the length of the string after it was modified.

This also assumes that you can load pieces of the file contents without having to parse everything as JSON then convert it back to a string. Also assumes that only one process is updating that key -- if multiple processes try to update it, the JSON value can get corrupted.